# Customizing exported pdf background color in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to export pdf of a webpage and I am having difficulty changing the background color of the generated pdf.

I successfully changed the bg color using print media CSS of the webpage. And it does render fine but the header, footer and marginal area that is not the part of the webpage doesn't change.

Is there a way to tell phantomjs using black as default color of the pdf pages?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.body.bgColor = 'black';
});
```

http://phantomjs.org/tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 2):

add media="all" to your css on pages you want to export, like:

```
<link href="my.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And then try the export again.